# Zabbix: Integrate with external system by formating and pushing polled/trap data?

Tags: zabbix

The Goal is to have Zabbix handle the SNMP polling and receiving of data from hosts, but push data to an external system which can handle persistence,visualization, and alerting (system already supports receiving posted data, but does support snmp/polling)

Is there an ideal way of achieving this? I tested with a script action that runs a bash script and does an HTTP post, but was wondering if there some integration that could help solve this in a more stable/scalable way.

The external service can be modified to fit with Zabbix in any way, it is just the getting the data out of Zabbix (w/out polling zabbix) that I am strugging with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Zabbix is intended to be that external system you have. If you pretend to use some other system, you could get SNMP values directly by your own, without using Zabbix at all. Zabbix's most powerful features are its database, visualization and triggers, among others. Getting the data is quite trivial compared to that. Check on `snmpget` and `snmpwalk` on linux.

Comment: I could recommend `grafana`. I set-up alerts in zabbix, and have all the visualization and export stuff done in grafana in seconds.

Comment: @eventHandler I am a bit concerned about development of a scalable snmp poller due to the potential number of nodes (+10000), and variety of configurations. Zabbix seemed like a solution that was already developed with those in mind and has a extensive api for integration.

Comment: When you call an external script from Zabbix, and that script performs a `hostdata=$(my_snmp_poll_function)`, why not send (scp, curl, grafana,..) the `"${hostdata}"` before ending the script?

Answer (score 1):

1. Zabbix reads SNMP traps from from a log file, so you can just read the same file with an external tool when you are working with traps.
2. The [real time export](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/install/real_time_export) is able to write all of Zabbix data to JSON files, that you can parse with a different tool.